# adjusting the tab bar in UItabView

Tags: tabbar

I have a situation where I have to a view a Tab Bar (with 4 tabs) (name it as TabBar 1) using a UITabView. On clicking the fourth tab, a new set of tabbar (name it ias TabBar 2) will be displayed with 3 tab items. Now I want the First tabbar - TabBar 1 to be visible at bottom and TabBar2 at top side of the screen. How to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use custom `tabbar` here, same like `tabview` cell is used for custom table view , same is applied for this kind of `Tabbar`.